# where to see created mysql database and tables

Tags: mysql

There is no mysql in `/var/lib` where I expected to find the databases and tables.

Answer (score 4):

There should be files named mysql at least at these locations

```
/etc/mysql/
/etc/init.d/
```

You can check if there is a running mysql with...

```
ps -ef |grep mysql
```

Or type `mysql` on command line. It will show an error if there is a mysql:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'xxxx'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

If there is no mysql in /etc/ you do not have it installed. `/var/lib/` is optional so not a good directory to test if you have a mysql instance; the location of the data directory is defined in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` (look for `datadir`). If that shows something other than `/var/lib/` you need to use that directory to find the database files.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the `datadir` in the various configuration files:

```
grep datadir /etc/mysql/my.cnf
grep datadir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
grep datadir /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
grep datadir ~/.my.cnf
```

---

By priority:

1. `~/.my.cnf`
2. `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

   With these lines in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

   ```
   !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
   !includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
   ```
3. `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

   With these lines in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

   ```
   !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
   !includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
   ```
4. `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

   If your changes are placed before the lines

   ```
   !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
   !includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
   ```

   If you make changes after this lines, than the priority is 2.

Comment: If you list it like that I would advice to include in what order these files are prioritized (I would assume ~/.my.cnf takes precedence but the other 3 I could make  case for any of them to be 1st priority ;) ).

Comment: @Braiam thank you o_O I don't know, why I used `cat`.